# How to connect to named instance with ODBC Driver 17 on PHP 7?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, php-7.1

I am trying to connect to an MS SQL database that is a named instance from my linux box running PHP 7.1. I am using ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.

I have successfully installed the ODBC driver from Microsoft and successfully connected to databases that are not named instances. For the named instance, I have tried every combination that I can think of (with/without port, quotes, brackets, etc.)

```
//$host = 'mySVR-SQL'; // THIS WORKS
//$host = '10.10.10.12345'; // THIS ALSO WORKS
$host = "SERV\INSTANCE_NAME"; // THIS DOES NOT WORK
$host = "SERV\INSTANCE_NAME,1433"; // THIS DOES NOT WORK
$host = "[SERV\INSTANCE_NAME]"; // THIS DOES NOT WORK
$host = '123.12.34.56\INSTANCE_NAME'; // THIS DOES NOT WORK
$user = 'my_username';
$pass = 'my_password';
$db = 'my_database';

$conn = "odbc:DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=$host;DATABASE=$db";

$db_c = new PDO($conn, $user, $pass);

//connection string without variables for troubleshooting
$db_c = new PDO("odbc:Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=123.12.34.56\INSTANCE_NAME;Database=MyDatabase", "my_username", "my_password");
```

This is the error message I get:

```
SQLSTATE[HYT00] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
```

What can I do to further troubleshoot this issue? Note that I was able to connect fine before using pdo_dblib drivers on php 5.6. But since we are upgrading to PHP 7, I figured we should use the microsoft drivers (which work fine, except for the named instance.)

This DOES work (using dblib):

```
$db_c = new PDO("dblib:host=123.12.34.56\INSTANCE_NAME;dbname=MyDatabase;charset=utf8", "my_username", "my_password");
```

Comment: If it is listen on port 1433, then it isn't named instance, but a default instance. Also, the part after the slash is the instance name, not the database name. Do not specify port for named instances, unless it is configured to not use dynamic ports. Simply provide host name in format `SERVER_NAME\INSTANCE_NAME`.

Comment: Yes, I am using the instance name after the slash, not the database name, I've updated my question with the correct syntax. I've removed the port and tested but it is still not finding the server.

Comment: Note that `SERVER_NAME` must be the DNS-resolvable hostname or IP address, not the Windows hostname.  Note also that you must remove `PORT=1433;` from your `$conn =` line.

Comment: Yes. I can ping the server_name from the linux box I am trying to connect from, but I also tried the connection with the IP address in place of the server name - still get the same error. I removed PORT=1433. I've updated the question with the revised connection string, sans port.

Comment: any update? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

For a MS SQL database with a named instance and a custom port this will work:

```
new \PDO("sqlsrv:Server=IP_ADDRESS\\INSTANCE_NAME,CUSTOM_PORT;Database=DATABASE_NAME", "my_username", "my_password");
```

You need to escape the backslash by using 2 backslashes. And if there is a custom port you need to include it in the connection string.